# How to create an NSData that is 4 bytes big?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata

I want to keep a GKSession alive with a scheduled reoccurring ping every 10 seconds. Some say the NSData object should be 4 bytes long.

how do I create such a ping NSData object with 4 bytes?
Like this?

```
int number = 1234;
NSData *pingData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&number length:4];
```

Or is there a simpler / more accurate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "four bytes" thing is central to the meaning of your code, it's probably preferable to type the variable as a `uint32_t`. That type is explicitly defined as being four bytes wide, while `int` is usually assumed to be four bytes but not really guaranteed to be so.

But your code for creating the data object is correct either way.

Comment: This is an important distinction to make.  However, in the era of 64-bit computing I don't think it is valid to say that `int` is assumed to be 4 bytes anymore, though.  As far as I know, `int` is the size of a single register on the processor that the OS mainly supports, so 2 bytes on 16-bit (e.g. MSDOS, basically defunct) , 4 bytes on 32-bit (e.g. iOS and older OS X) and 8 bytes on 64-bit (e.g. Modern OS X).  That way `int` is likely to be the data type that the target architecture is most efficient at using.

Comment: Even on 64 bit Macs, int is 4 bytes. Mac OS X is what's called an "LP64" system, meaning longs and pointers are 64 bit.

Comment: Yeah, like Catfish_Man said, this is more of a theoretical problem than a practical one at this point for Mac- or iOS-only programmers. But I still think it's better to write correct code in the first place rather than depend on ints being a certain width everywhere your code ever runs.